# iOS ApplePay PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController not appearing in Xcode11/iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

Our application has had ApplePay implemented for a number of years. Just recently I hit the button to trigger it to only find out the pay sheet from `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` doesn't appear. It won't slide up in a sandbox (i.e. simulator or device connected to Xcode) environment, but putting a breakpoint shows that it is being created successfully. It's been awhile since I've tested this, but I am suspecting something change with Xcode11 or iOS 13.

My code is pretty standard Apple Pay, but posted below.

```
        let item = PKPaymentSummaryItem()
        item.label = "Our Label"
        let price = NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: UInt64(totalPrice), exponent: -2, isNegative: false)
        item.amount = price

        items.append(item)

        request.paymentSummaryItems = items

        if let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) {
            applePayController.delegate = self
            present(applePayController, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems to be a simulator bug - trying running it on an actual device.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did do that. Went through the process of creating a sandbox tester, adding a sandbox credit card to device from Apple's list. But, still, even on the device no panel is displayed. Placing breakpoint at "present()" shows that it's being called with a non-nil object but nothing appears.

Comment: I faced the same issue some what closer to this but i did it in objective c- , if u would like to see i can attach it below

Comment: Try clearing your Derived Data folder and rebuild your app see if that helps. Set a breakpoint just before present(applePayController, animated: true) to see if it is getting called or drop a print statement to see if it is getting called.

Comment: Derived Data deleted. Breakpoint added confirmed that the present is getting called and that applePayController is not nil.

Comment: It was a simulator bug on Xcode 11 + iOS 13. Just tested on Xcode 11.2 beta 2 and  it's now working 

Comment: That's it! Thank you Douglas, if you make that the answer, you'll get yourself 500 reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, where Apple Pay suddenly stopped working in our app. We've also been supporting this for at least halve a year now.

Using the latest Xcode (Xcode 11.2, Beta 2 (11B44)), it seems to work again.

I'm guessing it was a Xcode bug then. Even though it's not listed in Xcode's release notes for [Xcode 11.1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_1_release_notes) or [Xcode 11.2 beta  2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_beta_2_release_notes).

Answer (score 6):

This will happen if the merchantID used by your `PKPaymentRequest` is not listed in mobile.entitlements.  Or if the MerchantID is not enabled by your app's provisioning profile.

View Controller

```
  PKPaymentRequest *request = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
  
  request.merchantIdentifier = "com.your.app.merchandId"
```

mobile.entitlements

```
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.in-app-payments</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.your.app.merchandId</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have pasted your snippet into my app, which uses ApplePay and I have run it on a test device which is sandboxed and has ApplePay enabled and the ApplePay button didn't work.

What I found it quite surprising.

When you look at the docs for PKPaymentSummaryItem it has only two initialisers:

> ```
> init(label: String, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
> init(label: String, amount: NSDecimalNumber, type:PKPaymentSummaryItemType)
> ```

And neither has default values, but you are initialising one with an empty initialiser. Surprisingly there are no errors or warnings and it even comes up in code completion. 
So I changed the initialiser:

```
let item = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Our Label",
                                amount: NSDecimalNumber(mantissa: UInt64(totalPrice),
                                                        exponent: -2,
                                                        isNegative: false))
request.paymentSummaryItems = [items]

if let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController(paymentRequest: request) {
    applePayController.delegate = self
    present(applePayController, animated: true)
}
```

And it works (on device only - not simulator)!

That made my wonder so I just changed your item from `let` to `var` and it works as well. I would still go with the documented initialiser.