# Stripe ApplePayContext fails to present payment sheet on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay, passkit

I'm trying to implement Apple Pay payment throught Stripe and PassKit. I've done the following to create an `STPAppleyPayContext`, and use its `presentApplePay(on:completion:)` method to display the Apple Pay payment sheet.

```swift
let merchantId = "A_VALID_MERCHANT_ID_HERE"
let currency = "usd"
let country = "US"
let paymentReq = Stripe.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: merchantId, country: country, currency: currency)

// Configure the line items on the payment request
let charge = NSDecimalNumber(value: 1000)
let summaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Service", amount: charge)]
paymentReq.paymentSummaryItems = summaryItems

if let applePayContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentReq, delegate: self) {
    print("--- presenting apple pay sheet")
    applePayContext.presentApplePay(on: self, completion: nil)
} else {
    print("--- failed to create STPApplePayContext, may be a problem with the Apple Pay config")
}
```

In the logs, `"--- presenting apple pay sheet"` was printed, so I believe `applePayContext.presentApplePay(on:completion:)` was successfully called. However, no sheet was presented, and I can't find any error logs.

The **exact** same code worked when we build the App on iOS 13, but it doesn't work on iOS 14. I am wondering if it is related some update to the Apple Pay system in iOS 14, or something else went wrong.

Comment: Is this on a simulator or a physical device? It wouldn't really surprise me if Apple Pay is broken on the new version of the simulator, it seems to happen every time until they fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58563489/ios-applepay-pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller-not-appearing-in-xcode11-ios-1

Comment: @karllekko It's broken on both simulators and real devices D:

Comment: @EricHua did you find a solution? Please share!

Comment: @MumtazHussain Hi unfortunately I didn't, maybe you can submit a ticket to Stripe